# python /usr/bin command not found

Tags: python, easy-install

System: Mountain Lion 10.8.

I tried to uninstall python 2.7 and therefore i also deleted /usr/bin/python.
However, after that i needed python again and i installed in again.
Now I want to use easy_install to install matlibplot etc..
Unfortunately, it says:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/easy_install: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

and also /usr/bin/python:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

however if i go to /usr/bin/ there are all version of python.

I also took a look to /usr/bin/easy_install; the first line says:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

BTW: i also installed python 3.2 and it also not "visible" outside /usr/bin

Do I need to fix any path variables?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does `which python` say? And just to be paranoid, `echo $PATH` to check that `/usr/bin` is in the path.

Comment: cd into the python directory and search for the easy_install command, /path/to/easy_install <module>. This is windows anyways, but it might be similar with mac.

Comment: Are any of the python versions actually named "python", or things like "python27" and "python32"?

Comment: What's the output pf `ls -l /usr/bin/python*`?

Comment: @DanielFischer which python says /opt/local/bin/python

Comment: @ernie ls -l says only 
    lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  75 28 Jul 16:27 /usr/bin/python2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  82 28 Jul 16:27 /usr/bin/python2.5-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5-config

lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  75 28 Jul 16:27 /usr/bin/python2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  82 28 Jul 16:27 /usr/bin/python2.6-config ->

Comment: Okay, that explains why it isn't found in `/usr/bin`. Make a symlink.

Comment: @ernie and furthermore 
../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6-config

but going into /usr/bin/ i can see:
python python2.5  python2.7-config python3.2-config pythonw2-32        pythonw3-32 python-32 python2.5-config python3 python3.2m pythonw2.5 pythonw3.2 python-config python2.6 python3-32         python3.2m-config  pythonw2.6         pythonw3.2-32
python2 python2.6-config   python3-config     pythonw            pythonw2.7 python2-32  python2.7 python3.2 pythonw-32 pythonw2.7-32 python2-config python2.7-32 python3.2-32 pythonw2 pythonw3

Comment: @DanielFischer a symlink like:
ln -s /opt/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python ?

Comment: If that's what `/opt/local/bin/python` points to, that's okay.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
Now everything is much more understandable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment, `ls -l /usb/bin/python*` shows:

```
 lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 75 28 Jul 16:27 /usr/bin/python2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5 
 lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 82 28 Jul 16:27 /usr/bin/python2.5-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5-conf??ig 
 lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 75 28 Jul 16:27 /usr/bin/python2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6 
 lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 82 28 Jul 16:27 /usr/bin/python2.6-config
```

Note that there is no `/usr/bin/python`.

As @Wouter mentioned, you'll want to create a symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python
```

That'll create a symlink (think of it as a shortcut in Windows), from `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python2.6`

For a bit more detail, you mention the first line of `/usr/bin/easy_install` is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

This is commonly known as the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line, and tells the script which interpretor to use - in this case it's trying to use `/usr/bin/python`, which, as we've seen from the ls command, does not exist, which is why we create a symlink

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
Now everything is much more understandable!

Answer (score 1):

Probably a missing symlink. Try:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.2 /usr/bin/python
```

You might need to replace the first argument to match the name of the python executable you found in /usr/bin

Comment: `python3` might be more preferable for python3.2. `python` should be reserve for Python 2

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Then the code above should be changed to symlink to a python 2.* to make the shebang work in easy_install

Answer (score 0):

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:${PATH}

should fix it.
Source: https://medium.com/faun/the-right-way-to-set-up-python-on-your-mac-e923ffe8cf8e